# Javascript Array Sorting and splicing

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I am making a game and I need sprites to find the closest "food" and head towards them. I am having trouble finding the right code to make this happen. They seem to get the first food just fine but when there are multiple food items the sprite is indecisive between each one and doesn't go far enough to eat any of them. Still don't have much deep experience with arrays to understand.

I'm using cocos2d framework.

```
update:function (dt) {

for (var i = 0; i < this._gubz.length; i++)
    {
        var gub = this._gubz[i];
        if (this._food.length>0)
            {
            var distances = new Array();

                 for (var w = 0; w < this._food.length; w++)
                 {
                 var food = this._food[w];
                 var location = food.getPosition();
                 var distance = cc.pDistance(location,gub.getPosition());
                 }

            var smallestDistance = Math.min.apply(Math,distances);
            var indexOfNumber = distances.indexOf(smallestDistance);
            var closestFood = this._food[indexOfNumber];

            gub.currentTarget = indexOfNumber;

            }
       }

       for (var i = 0; i < this.foodToRemove.length; i++)
        {
            this.removeChild(this.foodToRemove[i].GetUserData());
            this._food.splice(this._food.indexOf(this.foodToRemove[i].GetUserData()),1)
            this.world.DestroyBody(this.foodToRemove[i]);

        }



  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply sorting to a javascript array use the sort variable.

```
this._food = this._food.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.smallestDistance > b.smallestDistance ? -1 : a.smallestDistance < b.smallesDistance ? 1 : 0;
});
```

to remove items use the filter item:

```
this._food = this._food.filter(function(element) {
    return elementDoesNotExist(element);
});
```

Should get you started.

HTH